# ListView inside Gridview

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-adapter

I would like to use a GridView layout, so that every item of the Gridlayout has its own ListView. I have been looking for code sample but I haven't found any. Should I use different adapter classes for the GridView and the ListView?
Thank you in advance!

Edit: I have created a GridView that displays all the some tiles, and I want every grid item to include a list, so I have added a ListView to the layout of the GridView items. Unfortunately I 'm having problems connecting the listview to the adapter.

This is the **adapter of the gridView**:

```
public class MainViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Category> {
private Context mContext;
private int layoutResourceId;
private ArrayList<Category> mGridData = new ArrayList<Category>();
ArrayAdapter adapter;

public MainViewAdapter(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Category> mGridData) {
    super(mContext, layoutResourceId, mGridData);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mGridData = mGridData;
}

public void setGridData(ArrayList<Category> mGridData) {
    this.mGridData = mGridData;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    String imageUrl;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.SubListView = (ListView) row.findViewById(R.id.SubList);
        holder.titleTextView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.category_title);
        holder.simpleDraweeView = (SimpleDraweeView) row.findViewById(R.id.category_image);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    Category category = mGridData.get(position);
    Log.i("position", "" + position);
    holder.titleTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(category.getTitle()));
    imageUrl = category.getImage();
    Log.i("image url",imageUrl );
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(imageUrl);
    holder.simpleDraweeView.setImageURI(imageUri);

    List SubCategories = category.getSubCateg();
    Log.i("@MainViewAdapter - SubCategories", category.getSubCateg().toString());

    //list SubCategories to ArrayList
    ArrayList<SubCategory> listOfSub = new ArrayList<>(SubCategories.size());
    listOfSub.addAll(SubCategories);
    Log.i("listOfSub",listOfSub.toString());

    //ArrayList to ListView
    holder.SubListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView titleTextView;
    SimpleDraweeView simpleDraweeView;
    ListView SubListView;
}}
```

And here is the **adapter of the listview**:

```
public class SubListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SubCategory> {
private int layoutResourceId;
private ArrayList<SubCategory> mSubGridData = new ArrayList<SubCategory>();
ArrayAdapter adapter;

private final Context mContext;

public SubListAdapter(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<SubCategory> mSubGridData) {
    super(mContext, R.layout.subcategory_item, mSubGridData);

    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mSubGridData = mSubGridData;
}

public void setSubGridData(ArrayList<SubCategory> mSubGridData) {
    this.mSubGridData = mSubGridData;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    SubListAdapter.ViewHolder holder;
    String imageUrl;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.SubTitleTextView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.subCatItemTitle);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (SubListAdapter.ViewHolder) row.getTag();

    return rowView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView SubTitleTextView;
    ListView SubListView;
}}
```

I am having some problems with the second adapter.

Comment: You could just try it, and in case that it doesn't work ask a detailed question with what you did and a clear description of what doesn't work. Yes, you will need an adapter for every list / grid.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is Yes.
and also there is another solution.

- Add Relative/Linear Layout as items of GridView.
- In adapter class of GridView, add subItems to in @getView()
  dynamically.
  but I don't recommend it because of performance. it will take too long for this type view to load.

Write what do you need then I will update to my answer for another solution (if possible)
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You just create a GridView android setAdapter for it .in this adapter ,create a layout.xml which has a listView in it.then do it as usual.

ps:you would not get the real height of the nested listView if you use layout_width="warp_content". because nested listView couldn't get real height with "warp_content

Measure it would be fine .